# SANDBOX USER: This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, osx-elcapitan

It is apparently impossible to use the sandbox account to test receipt validation on OSX.

No solutions on SO work. Have someone figured this out?

This is a copy of radar 
http://www.openradar.me/23831039

Summary:
Seemingly new to 10.11.2, attempts to authenticate with a sandbox iTunesConnect user account are met with an error message:

"This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store."

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Create any submission-ready app for the MAS
2. Launch on 10.11.2
3. Supply Sandbox credentials

Expected Results:
The app should be validated with a _MASReceipt and launch as expected.

Actual Results:
A dialog is presented:

This Apple ID has not yet been used with the App Store.
Please review your information.

Version:
10.11.2

There is also this email from Apple, that we all have received, that probably has a relation to it. BTW, their solution of updating to
10.11.2 and restarting the computer, is useless, as expected:

> To help protect customers and developers, we require that all third party apps, passes for Apple Wallet, Safari Extensions, Safari
>   Push Notifications, and App Store purchase receipts are signed by a
>   trusted certificate authority. The Apple Worldwide Developer Relations
>   Certification Authority issues certificates that Apple uses to sign
>   apps on the Mac App Store and receipts that third party developers use
>   to prevent unauthorized copies of their apps from running. On February
>   14, 2016, the intermediate certificate will expire and receipt
>   signatures will include a renewed intermediate certificate.
>
> Since you may use receipt validation in your apps, we want to make you aware of potential issues your users may encounter due to the
>   renewed certificate. Users running OS X El Capitan (v10.11 or
>   v10.11.1) may receive a notification that your Mac app is damaged if
>   it utilizes receipt validation to request a new receipt from Apple.
>   They can resolve this issue by restarting their Mac or updating to OS
>   X El Capitan (v10.11.2).
>
> Mac App Store customers running OS X Snow Leopard (v10.6.8) will be unable to purchase new apps or run previously purchased apps that
>   utilize receipt validation until they install the OS X Snow Leopard
>   update, which will be available via OS X Software Update this January.
>
> Since different methods can be used for validating receipts, we recommend that you test your receipt validation code in the test
>   environment to ensure no implementation-specific issues exist. Make
>   sure that your code adheres to the Receipt Validation Programming
>   Guide and resolve any receipt validation issues by February 14.
>
> We apologize for any inconvenience. If you have any questions, contact us.
>
> Best regards, 
>   Apple Developer Relations

No solutions work like: creating a fresh sandbox user, transferring the project to a new one, cleaning the derived-data folders, cleaning the appstore cache folder of OS X, etc.

Comment: Have you tried doing a full project clean, rebooting your Mac, rebuilding your app, and running it? (Has been known to fix it.)

Comment: everything. Unfortunately, all solutions like this, already posted on SO, did not work. As indicated by that radar, it appears to be a new bug to join the club.

Comment: I've no idea what other solutions have been posted, manually wipe the caches? Create a new clean user account on the Mac and try it? Failing other solutions,  DTS are back on the 4th and will hopefully kick the appropriate machinery, so take a few days off :-) And try not to think about Feb 14 as 10.11.2 clearly is not yet fixed when it comes to the MAS and all things receipt related :-(

Comment: Unfortunately creating a fresh user did not solve the problem. This appears to be some deeper bug. This bug was reported to them on the beginning of december. Plenty of time to solve this urgent bug already. Probably someone reported before that. Apple is famous for having bugs rotting there for years without solution. DTS being on vacations is ridiculous too. That thing should work 24x7x365. Anyway, there is not much we can do.

Comment: Same Issue here. I also tried to make a clean build, restart my macbook and added a new sandbox account in ITC. As my app exits on launch with code 173 on missing of a MAS receipt, it cannot be something within my application logic. I also assume that apple broke this in 10.11.2 as all was well before.

Comment: Added additional radar issue: http://www.openradar.me/24055868

Comment: yes, Apple broke it on 10.11.2. I suspect all our users are not being able to run our apps anymore. That is outrageous because the initial radar is from the beginning of December. Plenty of time to release a fix for that.

Comment: Having the same issue: Posted on the dev forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/102044#102044

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After lot of days struggling, I am able to resolve the issue today.

1. Open Activity monitor and force- quit the following processes.
   storeaccountd, storeassetd, storedownloadd, and storeinappd .
2. Then go to ~/Library/Caches and delete corresponding folders with same names.

Comment: Unfortunately I did that but it is not solving the problem for me.

Comment: Try restrat your machine once

Comment: I did that several times.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that fixed it for me!

Comment: This fixed it for me as well

Comment: I can report that the bug is still present in 10.11.4—and the fix is still working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the steps and I figured out the answer.
In App store, terms and condition screen is missing/not populating properly.
Then I tried sign in Music/iTunes solved my problem.